# Why is this variable not parsed when placed inside a php function?

Tags: php

This code displays the html form but without a value (the submit box will be empty) generated by a mysql query.

```
<?php
function form() {
    echo "<form>
              <form action=\"page.php\" method=\"post\">
              <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\"$row[column]\">
              <input type=\"submit\">
          </form>";     
}

form();
?>
```

However, if I echo the following when *not* in a function the $row[column] array is echoed correctly:

```
<?php
echo "<form>
          <form action=\"page.php\" method=\"post\">
          <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\"$row[column]\">
          <input type=\"submit\">
      </form>";         
?>
```

The two codes are identical, except one is in a function. How do I get the array to be echoed when inside  a function? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem is one of variable scoping.  `$row` exists in the global scope.  From inside the function, the globally-scoped vairables are not available.

Here is link for further reading - https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

To resolve this, you must make `$row` available to the function.  There are generally two ways to do this.  The typically preferred way, is to inject the dependent variable into the function, by passing it as parameter:

```
function form($row) {
    // work with $row inside function
}
```

This is known as "dependency injection".

A second way (which really should not be used, but I show it here because you may encounter it in existing code/code examples) would be to simply use the `global` keyword to make the global variable available in function scope:

```
function form() {
    global $row;
    // work with $row inside function
}
```

Comment: honestly i wouldn't even mention `global` as an option even if it's technically something that *can* be done

Comment: @CrayonViolent I only mention it because at some point, the OP is likely to come across this usage.  I want to point it out so that he understands what the intent is, while also mentioning this is not a good approach.

Comment: fair enough, though to be honest, in my own experience, the only time i *ever* see it brought up or used is when people are pointing out how it's possible to do it that way but caution against it! ;)

Comment: Thank you very much for the help! Also, thanks for pointing out the two different ways of working around the problem. I'll keep this in mind as I progress with PHP.

Comment: @CrayonViolent There are still a ton of PHP code samples on the interwebs that have this usage, as well as a number of widely distributed open source applications that do this. This is kind of like `mysql_*` functions, a vestage of a bygone era in PHP programming that unfortunately still clutters the internet and leads to misuse.

Comment: @user3365553 do *not* use `global`. There is literally nothing it can solve that something else can't, and it completely destroys the whole point of having scope.

Comment: @user3365553 I echo Crayon Violent's sentiment, that you should not use `global`.  In fact, I will change the wording of my answer to be more strong on this point.

Answer (score 2):

You must have $row defined somewhere outside of the function scope. Try this:

```
<?php
function form( $row ) {
    echo "<form>
              <form action=\"page.php\" method=\"post\">
              <input type=\"text\" name=\"name\" value=\"$row[column]\">
              <input type=\"submit\">
          </form>";     
}

form( $row );
?>
```

Comment: I can't believe how many insane explanations surfaced before someone said something correct. plus 1

Answer (score 0):

Because of different scope between variables inside function and outside function, take it easy, variables inside function are not same as outside, for example: if you defined one variable outside function, its not accessible inside function by usual way, instead, you can use function parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use **Here Document**?

```
<?php

function form($value) {
// Do not forget to escape input value
$value = htmlspecialchars($value, ENT_QUOTES, 'UTF-8');
echo <<<EOD
<form action="page.php" method="post">
<input type="text" name="name" value="{$value}">
<input type="submit">
</form>  
EOD;
}

form($row['column']);
```

Comment: an excellent suggestion.. that has nothing to do with the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd really like to put the variable there you should use `$GLOBALS`, also you should use the `.` operator instead of `+` to concatenate strings, so it is `... value=\"" . $GLOBALS['row']['column'] . "\"> ...`.

Although using global values in functions is not best practice approach (to say the least), especially when a straight print is using them - see `strip_tags()`, `htmlspecialchars()`, `htmlentities()` and their friends.

Instead of using global variable you should use function parameters, so in your case it is:

```
<?php
  function form($row) {
      echo "... " . htmlspecialchars($row['column']) . " ...";
  }

  form($row);
?>
```